# C# switch fallthrough error?

Tags: c#

I have no idea why I'm getting this following error:

> Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case "h":') to another (CS0163)

Only for H and S - quite strange.

```
switch(myChoice)
{
    case "K":
    case "k":
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Kanto region");
        break;
    case "O":
    case "o":
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Orange Islands");
        break;
    case "J":
    case "j":
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Johto region");
        break;
    case "H":
    case "h":
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Hoenn region");
    case "S":
    case "s":
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Sinoh region");
    case "U":
    case "u":
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Unova region");
        break;
    case "R":
    case "r":
        Console.WriteLine("Return");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid choice", myChoice);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up: You have asked three questions now where there is an acceptable answer. You should accept those answers by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: oh gosh thanks ><, I never knew about that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fallthrough only works when the case statement has no body. Since your "h" and "s" cases have code present, you need a `break` after them.

Additionally, as a suggestion: you could do a `String.ToUpper()` on your `switch` parameter so you can avoid having to check for both the lowercase and uppercase variants of `myChoice`. Your `switch` statement then becomes:

```
switch(myChoice.ToUpper())
{
    case "K":
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Kanto region");
        break;
    case "O":
        ...
}
```

Comment: not necessarily. There should be a break, return or a goto at this place. See my answer with goto's below..

Answer (score 11):

You're missing the `break` after the s and h cases

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `break;` - from the documentation on the switch statement, ["Unlike C++, C# does not allow execution to continue from one switch section to the next."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the break statement between H and S.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the

`break;`

Statement...

```
case "H":
case "h":
     Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Hoenn region");
     break;
case "S":
case "s":
     Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Sinoh region");
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

After case "H" add a goto case "h"
After case "S" add a goto case "s"

```
case "H":
    goto case "h";
case "h":
    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Hoenn region");
    break;
case "S":
    goto case "s";
case "s":
    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Sinoh region");
    break;
```

Yes, with C#  goto's are back!